# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Beziehung und Verhältnis?

Tags: word-usage

Mit wem hat man eine Beziehung?  Mit wem ein Verhältnis?  Wann impliziert "Beziehung" Affäre?  Was sind die richtigen Präpositionen?

Comment: Ähnlich: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11054/comparison-of-german-words-describing-various-degrees-of-a-romantic-relationship

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparison of German words describing various degrees of a romantic relationship](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11054/comparison-of-german-words-describing-various-degrees-of-a-romantic-relationship)

Comment: PSA: we do not consider a question a duplicate of another if one is in English and the other in German.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Bezeichnungen können größtenteils synonym verwendet werden. Es besteht jedoch ein feiner, gradueller Unterschied, allerdings abhängig vom Standpunkt des Beobachters und Sprechers.

[**Wiktionary: Beziehung**](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Beziehung)

> **Bedeutungen:**
>   1] Verhältnis, in dem Menschen oder Organisationen zueinander stehen
>   2] wechselseitiges Verhältnis zwischen beliebigen Objekten
>   3] Partnerschaft zwischen zwei Menschen
>
> **Synonyme:**
>   1] Verbindung, Verhältnis
>   2] Bezug, Kontext, Relation, Zusammenhang
>   3] Liebschaft

[**Duden: Beziehung**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beziehung)

> **Bedeutungsübersicht**
>   Verbindung, Kontakt zwischen Einzelnen oder Gruppen
>   innerer Zusammenhang, wechselseitiges Verhältnis
>
> **Synonyme zu Beziehung** 
>   Fühlung, Kontakt, Umgang, Verbindung, Verhältnis, Verkehr; (bildungssprachlich) Konnex
>   Liebesverhältnis, Liebschaft, Romanze; (umgangssprachlich) Beziehungskiste, Techtelmechtel, Verhältnis; (abwertend) Liebelei; (bildungssprachlich veraltend) Liaison
>   Bezug, Verbindung, Verhältnis, Zusammenhang; (bildungssprachlich) Konnex; (Fachsprache) Nexus; (bildungssprachlich, Fachsprache) Relation

[**Wiktionary: Verhältnis**](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verh%C3%A4ltnis)

> **Bedeutungen:**
>   1] eine Beziehung, bei der zwei Dinge oder zwei Sachverhalte miteinander verglichen werden
>   2] persönliche Beziehung zweier Menschen
>   3] umgangssprachlich: intime Beziehung zwischen zwei Menschen
>   4] meist im Plural: Umschreibung einer bestimmten sozialen Lage oder bestimmter sozialer Lebensumstände
>
> **Synonyme:**
>   1] Relation, Beziehung 
>   3] Liebschaft, Liebelei, Techtelmechtel 
>   4] Umstand
>
> **Unterbegriffe:**
>   1] Auftragsverhältnis, Unterauftragsverhältnis), Bauverhältnis, Druckverhältnis, Größenverhältnis, Kosten-Nutzen-Verhältnis, Kräfteverhältnis, Lichtverhältnis (Lichtbrechungsverhältnis), Lüftungsverhältnis, Mischungsverhältnis, Missverhältnis, Preis-Leistungs-Verhältnis, Seitenverhältnis, Spannungsverhältnis, Stimmenverhältnis, Teilverhältnis, Torverhältnis, Verkehrsverhältnisse
>   2] Abhängigkeitsverhältnis, Arbeitsverhältnis, Beamtenverhältnis, Eigentumsverhältnis, Schuldverhältnis, Vertragsverhältnis, Vertrauensverhältnis, Vorgesetztenverhältnis
>   3] Bratkartoffelverhältnis, Liebesverhältnis
>   4] Lebensverhältnis, Machtverhältnis, Wohnverhältnis
>   4] Familienverhältnisse

[**Duden: Verhältnis**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Verhaeltnis)

> **Bedeutungsübersicht**
>   Beziehung, in der sich etwas mit etwas vergleichen lässt oder in der etwas an etwas anderem gemessen wird; Relation
>   Art, wie jemand zu jemandem, etwas steht; persönliche Beziehung
>   (umgangssprachlich) über eine längere Zeit bestehende intime Beziehung zwischen zwei Menschen; Liebesverhältnis
>   jemand, mit dem man ein Verhältnis hat
>   Umstände, äußere Zustände; für jemanden, etwas bestimmende Gegebenheiten
>
> **Synonyme zu Verhältnis**
>   Beziehung, Bezug, Verbindung, Verknüpfung, Zusammenhang; (bildungssprachlich) Konnex; (Fachsprache) Nexus; (bildungssprachlich, Fachsprache) Relation
>   Kontakt, [persönliche] Beziehung, Umgang, Verbindung
>   [Liebes]beziehung, Liebesverhältnis, Liebschaft, Romanze; (umgangssprachlich) Beziehungskiste, Techtelmechtel; (abwertend) Liebelei; (veraltend) Affäre; (bildungssprachlich veraltend) Liaison; (besonders in sozialen Netzwerken) Beziehungsstatus
>   Freund, Freundin, Geliebter, Geliebte, Liebespartner, Liebespartnerin, Liebhaber, Liebhaberin, Lover

In der Ausgangsfrage wird schon deutlich, dass der Übergang absolut weich fließend ist. "Wann impliziert 'Beziehung' Affäre?"

Das liegt allgemein im Auge des Betrachters. Dauer, Initimität und Intensität – in ihrer jeweiligen Betrachtungsart und abhängig vom Standpunkt des Uerteilers – spielen da hinein.

1. Eine "erwischte" Fremdgeherin schätzt ihre Affäre als kurzlebiges, unbedeutendes Verhältnis ein, und stellt dies auf Nachfrage auch genauso dar, während der gehörnte Mann sich schon in einer unfreiwilligen Dreier*beziehung* sieht.
2. Eine "erwischte" Fremdgeherin schätzt ihr Verhältnis als kurzlebige, unbedeutende Affäre ein, und stellt dies auf Nachfrage auch genauso dar, während der gehörnte Mann sich schon in einer unfreiwilligen Dreier*beziehung* sieht.
3. Eine "erwischte" Fremdgeherin schätzt ihre Beziehung als kurzlebige, unbedeutende Affäre ein, und stellt dies auf Nachfrage auch genauso dar, während der gehörnte Mann sich schon in einer unfreiwilligen Dreier*verhältnis* sieht.
4. Eine "erwischte" Fremdgeherin schätzt ihr Verhältnis als kurzlebiges, unbedeutende Beziehung ein, und stellt dies auf Nachfrage auch genauso dar, während der gehörnte Mann sich schon in einer unfreiwilligen Dreier*affäre* sieht.

Die Varianten sind weitestgehend identisch. Nur die Beziehung klingt irgendwie ein klein wenig dauerhafter, länger, ernsthafter. Daher fällt lediglich Beispiel 3 etwas aus dem Rahmen, da durch die gewählten Wörter in ihrer Reihenfolge die Worte einen zunächst seltsamen, dann noch denkwürdigeren Sinn zu erhalten scheinen. Ohne diese Ballung an beinah Synonymen fällt eine eindeutige Klassifizierung auf der reinen, isolierten Wortebene recht schwer.

Neben den beiden Synonymen Verhältnis und Beziehung ist die Affäre tendentiell eher

> [**Bedeutungen:**](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aff%C3%A4re)
>   [1](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Beziehung) skandalöses Vorkommnis, peinliche Angelegenheit
>   [2](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beziehung) Liebesabenteuer, (außereheliches) Liebesverhältnis

Eine äußerst schwache Hierarchie ließe sich demnach so aufstellen:
Beziehung > Verhältnis > Affäre

Eine solche Unterscheidung auf der prinzipiellen Ebene aufrechterhalten zu wollen, scheint aber etwas altbacken zu sein.

Answer (score 2):

Sowohl **Beziehung** als auch **Verhältnis** sind in diesem Fall Euphemismen für

> Liebesbeziehung, sexuelle Beziehung, Liebesverhältnis, sexuelles Verhältnis

Der Unterschied besteht im allgemeinen darin, dass die *Beziehung* als geregelt empfunden wird, während ein *Verhältnis* als dem *Lotterleben* zugehörig gilt.

> Katrin und Maik haben eine Beziehung.

Jeder, der es wissen muss, weiß das.

> Katrin und Maik haben ein Verhältnis.

Es ist ein mehr oder weniger offenes Geheimnis, dass sie ihre eigentlichen Partner betrügen.

Answer (score 1):

Vielleicht können dir weitere Beispielsätze helfen.

*Zu meinem neuen Nachbarn habe ich kein besonders enges Verhältnis* (= ich halte Abstand; ich finde ihn nicht besonders sympathisch)*, und eine Beziehung* (= eine partnerschaftliche Beziehung) *haben wir schon gar nicht.* (= wir sind kein Paar; wir sind keine Lebenspartner)

Der Aspekt 'Affäre' schwingt hier nirgendwo mit. 'Affäre' bedeutet immer 'eine sexuelle Beziehung', tendenziell heimlich und ohne hehre Ziele, **wenn** es sich auf zwei Personen bezieht.

*Der Schauspieler XYZ hat ständig neue Beziehungen.* = er glaubt jedesmal daran, dass es 'etwas Ernstes' sei, dass er diesmal 'die Richtige' gefunden hätte - bis dann die Nächste auftaucht, die noch interessanter, noch schöner ist.

*Der Schauspieler XYZ hat ein Verhältnis nach dem anderen.* = er steigt ständig mit einer Anderen in die Kissen, andere Absichten hat er nicht.

Cheers!

*Ach ja, XYZ und seine Affären ...* = XYZ ist in festen Händen, aber er kann's nicht lassen, es folgt ein Seitensprung auf den anderen.

---

Jenseits aller emotionalen und/oder sexuellen Bindungen und/oder Vorkommnissse:

*Die Beziehungen zwischen Israel und dem Iran sind angespannnt.*

*Er verdient wirklich gut und ist trotzdem ständig blank. Er hat einfach kein Verhältnis zu(m) Geld.*